# kafka MockConsumer throwing exception error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Subscription to topics, partitions and pattern are mutually exclusive

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to Unit test my kafka consumer. I am trying to use `MockConsumer` class which comes with `kafka-client` java api. 
Below is my configuration code

```
@Bean
public MockConsumer consumer(){

    MockConsumer consumer = new MockConsumer(OffsetResetStrategy.LATEST);
    consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(new TopicPartition("test-topic", 0)));

    HashMap<TopicPartition, Long> beginningOffsets = new HashMap<>();
    beginningOffsets.put(new TopicPartition("test-topic", 0), 0L);
    consumer.updateBeginningOffsets(beginningOffsets);

    consumer.addRecord(new ConsumerRecord<String, String>("test-topic",0,
            0L, "mykey", "myvalue0"));
    consumer.addRecord(new ConsumerRecord<String, String>("test-topic", 0,
            1L, "mykey", "myvalue1"));
    consumer.addRecord(new ConsumerRecord<String, String>("test-topic", 0,
            2L, "mykey", "myvalue2"));
    consumer.addRecord(new ConsumerRecord<String, String>("test-topic", 0,
            3L, "mykey", "myvalue3"));
    consumer.addRecord(new ConsumerRecord<String, String>("test-topic", 0,
            4L, "mykey", "myvalue4"));
    HashMap<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets = new HashMap<>();
    endOffsets.put(new TopicPartition("test-topic", 0), 4L);
    consumer.updateEndOffsets(endOffsets);
    return consumer;
}
```

Now When I am using this MockConsumer Bean in my test case like below

```
@Autowired
MockConsumer kafkaConsumer;

@Autowired
@InjectMocks
MyConsumer myConsumer; //this is the class having consumer code. This 
                      //is the class under test

@Test
public void testConsumeWithAutoAssignment() throws Exception {
  myConsumer.consumeTopic("test-topic");
}
```

I am getting exception from

`kafkaConsumer.subscribe(topic)`

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Subscription to topics, partitions and pattern are mutually exclusive`

Please let me know if anyone has found the issue or fixed this.

Comment: I refactored my code to test only processConsumerRecords and not testing ```subscribe``` method.

Answer (score 9):

This is because in the bean you are using `consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(new TopicPartition("test-topic", 0)));` which means that the consumer wants to consume from a specific partition (0) from the "test-topic". Then somewhere but I don't see where from the code you provided there is a call to `subscribe(topic)`. With subscribe, the consumer becomes part of a consumer group and the Kafka broker assign partitions automatically (for re-balancing). You can't use both : assigning specific partition (USER DEFINED) and subscribing with auto assigning.

Comment: Is there any way to unit test consumer. I am using ```MockConsumer```. and for unit test I need to assign partition to the consumer so that it can be consumed during test. Is there any other way to do it? I know that because subscription type becomes USER DEFINED it is not subscribable.

Comment: I think this is your rescue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42207232/731894 Basically, use ```rebalance``` not ```assign``` to set partition and set partition, update offset and add record after the ```subscribe``` call

Comment: This is not a good answer. Anybody who has a working consumer which subscribes to a topic and consumes it and then comes up with unit testing this using MockConsumer will face exactly this issue. To mock the MockConsumer, you need to assign before adding records. In your production code, there's a subscribe call -> BOOM.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue, the workaround for this is to assign `new TopicPartition(topic, 0)` to a variable and use that. Following code works for me:

```
TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);
consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(topicPartition));
HashMap<TopicPartition, Long> beginningOffsets = new HashMap<>();
beginningOffsets.put(topicPartition, 0L);
consumer.updateBeginningOffsets(beginningOffsets);
consumer.addRecord(new ConsumerRecord<>(topic, 0, 0L, "some-key", "some-value"));
```